# Draw line and Cut off Circuler area

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computational-geometry, image-segmentation

I have got the below Image after running the below code.

[image]

```
file='grayscale.png';
I=imread(file);
bw = im2bw(I);
bw = bwareaopen(bw,870);
imwrite(bw,'noiseReduced.png')
subplot(2,3,1),imshow(bw);
[~, threshold] = edge(bw, 'sobel');
fudgeFactor = .5;
im = edge(bw,'sobel', threshold * fudgeFactor);
subplot(2,3,2), imshow(im), title('binary gradient mask');

se = strel('disk',5);
closedim = imclose(im,se);
subplot(2,3,3), imshow(closedim), title('Connected Cirlces');
cc = bwconncomp(closedim);

S = regionprops(cc,'Centroid'); //returns the centers S(2) for innercircle
numPixels = cellfun(@numel,cc.PixelIdxList);
[biggest,idx] = min(numPixels);
im(cc.PixelIdxList{idx}) = 0;
subplot(2,3,4), imshow(im), title('Inner Cirlces Only');
c = S(2);
```

My target is now to draw a red cirle around the circular object(see image) and cut the circle region(area) from the original image 'I' and save the cropped area as image or perform other tasks. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can optimize/fit the circle with least `r` that contains all the points:

```
bw = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/il0Va.png');
[yy xx]=find(bw);
```

Now, let `p` be a three vector parameterizing a circle: `p(1), p(2)` are the x-y coordinates of the center and `p(3)` its radii. Then we want to minimize `r` (i.e., `p(3)`):

```
obj = @(p) p(3);
```

Subject to all points inside the circle

```
con = @(p) deal((xx-p(1)).^2+(yy-p(2)).^2-p(3).^2, []);
```

Optimizing with [`fmincon`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html):

```
[p, fval] = fmincon(obj, [mean(xx), mean(yy), size(bw,1)/4], [],[],[],[],[],[],con);
```

Yields

```
p =
471.6397  484.4164  373.2125
```

Drawing the result

```
imshow(bw,'border','tight');
colormap gray;hold on;
t=linspace(-pi,pi,1000);
plot(p(3)*cos(t)+p(1),p(3)*sin(t)+p(2),'r', 'LineWidth',1);
```

[image]

You can generate a binary mask of the same size as `bw` with `true` in the circle and `false` outside

```
msk = bsxfun(@plus, ((1:size(bw,2))-p(1)).^2, ((1:size(bw,1)).'-p(2)).^2 ) <= p(3).^2;
```

The mask looks like:

[image]

Comment: what is 'img' in the fmincon?

Comment: Your solution is correct. But instead of binary mask I want to crop the circle area. I mean  lets say I got "bw" from image "I". So How can I crop the detected circle from "I"? Or apply the binary mask on "I" so that the only circle area remains unchanged and rest of the region becomes black?

Comment: `cropped = bsxfun(@times, I, msk);` @Nektar

Comment: If i put the latest line I got an error

"Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles." 
And FYI "I" is gray scale image.

Comment: @Nektar `cropped=im2double(I).*msk;`@Nektar

Comment: Is it possible to apply any operation only in the inner area of the circle we found? Like taking the mean of the pixel values of the circle area. Not considering rest of the region?

Answer (score 1):

The convexhull of the white pixels will give you a fairly good approximation of the circle. You can find the center as the centroid of the area of the hull and the radius as the average distance from the center to the hull vertices.